# Node.js reading a blob with azure and creating a SAS token

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

So I am currently writing some code that gets a container and then selects a blob and makes a SAS token. which all currently work but I get a error when I try to open the link.

The error being given is this.

`AuthenticationFailed`
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:somethingsomething
The specified signed resource is not allowed for the this resource level

```js
const test = () => {
  const keyCredit = new StorageSharedKeyCredential('storageaccount', 'key')
  const sasOptions = {
  containerName: 'compliance',
  blobName: 'swo_compliance.csv',
};

  sasOptions.expiresOn = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600 * 1000);
  sasOptions.permissions = BlobSASPermissions.parse("r");


   const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(sasOptions, keyCredit).toString();
   console.log(`SAS token for blob container is: url/?${sasToken}`);

return `url/?${sasToken}`;

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include how your SAS URL looks like.

Comment: Hi @Adrianibar , If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the scenario in my system able to download the blob using the sas token

While you returning the **`return url/?${sasToken};`** in your code remove the **`“/”`** just give the
the **`return url?${sasToken};`**

Example URL : **`https://StorageName.blob.core.windows.net/test/test.txt?SASToken`**

I tried  in my system able to download blob

[image]